# Android Google Maps - how to provide updated custom tile

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I run server with my proprietary map tiles, used by the Google Maps v2 API in my Android app. I frequently generate new updated tiles, and need the users' maps to reflect these. How do I inform the Google Maps API that a particular tile should be invalidated and re-requested? I do not want to use `clearTileCache()` as this will also needlessly clear tiles which have not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `clearTileCache`. To avoid unnecessary recalculation of unchanged tiles let the tile provider read from your own cache that keeps the tiles in a map with a key which is build from the zoom level and the x and y coordinates of the tiles.